# model.matrix Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, operator-keyword, model.matrix

I ran into this error when using 'model.matrix'.

```
data_A <- data.frame(X1 = c("Y","N"), X2 = c(20,24), Y = c("N","Y"))
data_A
model.matrix("Y ~ X1 + X2", data_A)
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

What's causing the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examine `?model.matrix`. A snippet:

```
     ## Default S3 method:
     model.matrix(object, data = environment(object),
                  contrasts.arg = NULL, xlev = NULL, ...)

Arguments:

  object: an object of an appropriate class.  For the default method, a
          model formula or a ‘terms’ object.
```

Your `object` is a string formula while `data` is `data_A`. The `object` argument should be a formula or terms object as stated. Try

```
model.matrix(Y ~ X1 + X2, data_A)
```

or equivalently (if you are constructing the formula from a string)

```
model.matrix(as.formula(Y ~ X1 + X2), data_A)
```